# how to iterate over multiple links and scrape everyone of them one by one and save the output in csv using python beautifulsoup and requests

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this code but don't know how to read the links from a CSV or a list. I want to read the links and scrape details off every single link and then save the data in columns respected to each link into an output CSV.

Here is the code I built to get specific data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/282231178856"
r = requests.get(url)

x = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# print(x.prettify().encode('utf-8'))

# time to find some tags!!

# y = x.find_all("tag")

z = x.find_all("h1", {"itemprop": "name"})

# print z
# for loop done to extracting the title.
for item in z:
    try:
        print item.text.replace('Details about ', '')
    except:
        pass
# category extraction done

m = x.find_all("span", {"itemprop": "name"})

# print m

for item in m:
    try:
        print item.text
    except:
        pass

# item condition extraction done
n = x.find_all("div", {"itemprop": "itemCondition"})

# print n

for item in n:
    try:
        print item.text
    except:
        pass

# sold number extraction done

k = x.find_all("span", {"class": "vi-qtyS vi-bboxrev-dsplblk vi-qty-vert-algn vi-qty-pur-lnk"})

# print k

for item in k:
    try:
        print item.text
    except:
        pass

# Watchers extraction done

u = x.find_all("span", {"class": "vi-buybox-watchcount"})

# print u

for item in u:
    try:
        print item.text
    except:
        pass

# returns details extraction done

t = x.find_all("span", {"id": "vi-ret-accrd-txt"})

# print t

for item in t:
    try:
        print item.text
    except:
        pass

#per hour day view done
a = x.find_all("div", {"class": "vi-notify-new-bg-dBtm"})

# print a

for item in a:
    try:
        print item.text
    except:
        pass

#trending at price
b = x.find_all("span", {"class": "mp-prc-red"})

#print b

for item in b:
    try:
        print item.text
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is kind of vague!

Which links are you talking about? There are a hundred on a single ebay page. Which infos would you like to scrape? Similarly there is also a ton.

But anyway, here is I would proceed:

```
# First, create a list of urls you want to iterate on 

urls = []
soup = (re.text, "html.parser")

# Assuming your links of interests are values of "href" attributes within <a> tags 
a_tags = soup.find_all("a")
for tag in a_tags:
    urls.append(tag["href"])

# Second, start to iterate while storing the info
info_1, info_2 = [], []
for link in urls:
    # Do stuff here, maybe its time to define your existing loops as functions?
    info_a, info_b = YourFunctionReturningValues(soup)
    info_1.append(info_a)
    info_2.append(info_b)
```

Then if you want a nice csv output:

```
# Don't forget to import the csv module
with open(r"path_to_file.csv", "wb") as my_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(final_csv, delimiter = ",")
    csv_writer.writerows(zip(urls, info_1, info_2, info_3))
```

Hope this will help?

Of course, don't hesitate to give additional info, so to have additional details

On attributes with BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

About the csv module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was a nieve mistake not to share the links. I am talking about the main URL for the items page itself which follows this structure --> http://ebay.com/itm/<item_ID>. I have thousand's of item id so that I can put each item id's into a list using your example code above and then join each one of them using some other tutorials for URL joining and loop through them to scrape the data I need and then save the data into a new CSV which I want to create using the code itself, I'll write a sample code again and post it here for your kind review in order to learn more.

Comment: Hey, maybe you should now close this question. I think you got the structure right so start breaking down the problem into different pieces. Namely (1) defining a function to detect a page's html elements which are of interest to you with beautiful soup, (2) how to store the collected infos, (3) how to write down to a csv file :) Give it a (good) try and maybe come back with more precise questions later! Believe me, you have understood how it works